# How to build a ListView with currency masked EditText

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-edittext

I am developping an application that needs a ListView with currency masked EditText and a summary TextView showing the sum of the items.

I made a custom adapter. The currency mask (format BRL R$ 0.000,00) is working.
How to make it sum the values when user types in the EditText of each item?

Here is the code of Adapter:

```
public AdapterFaturamentoMes(Context context, ArrayList<FaturamentoMes> lista) {
    this.context = context;
    this.lista = lista;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    FaturamentoMes item = lista.get(position);
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_lista_faturamento_mes, parent, false);
    }

    TextView txtFaturamentoMes = view.findViewById(R.id.txtFaturamentoMes);
    EditText edFaturamento  = view.findViewById(R.id.edFaturamento);

    txtFaturamentoMes.setText(String.format(context.getString(R.string.txt_faturamento_mes), numberFormat.format(item.getMes()), numberFormat.format(item.getAno())));
    edFaturamento.setText(decimalFormat.format(item.getValor()));

    TextWatcher oldListener = (TextWatcher) edFaturamento.getTag();
    if (oldListener != null) edFaturamento.removeTextChangedListener(oldListener);

    TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
        double valor;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!s.toString().equals(atual)) {
                edFaturamento.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                String texto = s.toString().replaceAll("[.,]", "");
                valor = Double.parseDouble("0" + texto);
                String valorFormatado = decimalFormat.format(valor/100);
                atual = valorFormatado;

                edFaturamento.setText(valorFormatado);
                edFaturamento.setSelection(valorFormatado.length());
                edFaturamento.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    };

    edFaturamento.setTag(watcher);
    edFaturamento.addTextChangedListener(watcher);

    return view;
}

public ArrayList<FaturamentoMes> getLista() {
    return lista;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.lista.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public FaturamentoMes getItem(int position) {
    return this.lista.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
} 
}
```

Comment: At first, I recommend use to switch your ListView into a RecyclerView which is much more optimized. Then, you should refresh your ListView each time the `OnTextChanged()` method is called.

Comment: Thanks. 
But why don't you answer the question instead of comment?